# What kinds of values can a Number type hold?

Tags: javascript, primitive

I've read somewhere that a JavaScript number can hold both a 64-bit number AND a 64-bit Integer, is this true? I'm still a little confused on this stuff.

Comment: JavaScript has a single numeric type, it's not integers AND...numbers?

Comment: I think this pretty much answers your question https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number can contains integer or floating point number. Here are max/min values for JS

```js
console.log('float min:',Number.MIN_VALUE);
console.log('float max:',Number.MAX_VALUE);

console.log('int min:',Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);
console.log('int max:',Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
```

More details in [specification ES2018](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type)

Comment: I see! So, if I try to write an integer past that max integer limit it will be a float instead?

Comment: No, still integer but "alternative math"... try `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2`

Comment: @Alex JS does not have integers at all. It's floats only. If you have a bigger value than MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, then mathematical operations become unreliable

Comment: @VLAZ it depends of definition of integer number - I use [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) and I aware that JS operates only on subset of rational numbers

Comment: I see. So that's why the "alternate math" appears that's when it goes beyond the 15-16 digit limit of MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. As it has reached it's maximum precision and must start making approximations that are typical with floats.

Comment: @Alex you can use `BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)+2n` (chrome) to overcome this, however BigInt are not yet implement by all browsers (e.g. ff, but some libaries exists which allows big-int)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski usually in programming the type of number is determined by how it's represented by the programming language. So, if you are in Java and declare `float num = 2.0` that is still going to be referred to as a float, even if it represents the integer `2`. The key point is that any mathematical operations would treat this as one type not another. In Java integer division yields an integer - `3 / 2 --> 1` and a floating point division yields a floating point number - `3.0 / 2.0 --> 1.5`. In JS, since all numbers are floating point numbers, you can't get an int `3 / 2 --> 1.5`

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript only has a single numeric type for primitives - it's a IEEE 754 standard 64-bit double precision floating point number.

[Link to the specifications](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type)

[Link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type)

So, there are no integers in JavaScript - everything is a float.